# unable to call main procedure from wrapper procedure asynchronously

Tags: oracle, plsql, plsql-package

I want to call main procedure from the wrapper procedure. Wrapper procedure I'm able to output with dbms output print line but I'm unable to print within the main proc, looks like the main proc is not called from wrapper procedure. Please help me

Below is the table script

```
CREATE TABLE ASYNC_SAMPLE_TAB
( attribute1 varchar2(50),
  attribute2 varchar2(50)
);
```

Below is my package specification

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE XX_ASYNC_DEMO_PKG
IS
    PROCEDURE MAIN_PROC( 
        attribute1          IN      VARCHAR2,
        attribute2          IN      VARCHAR2
    );
    
    PROCEDURE WRAPPER_MAIN_PROC( 
        attribute1          IN      VARCHAR2,
        attribute2          IN      VARCHAR2
    );
  
END XX_ASYNC_DEMO_PKG;
```

Below is my package bofy

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY XX_ASYNC_DEMO_PKG
IS
    PROCEDURE WRAPPER_MAIN_PROC( 
            attribute1          IN      VARCHAR2,
            attribute2          IN      VARCHAR2
        )
    AS
    BEGIN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('-- START OF WRAPPER PROC---' || SYSTIMESTAMP);
        dbms_scheduler.create_job(
            job_name   => 'ASYNC_MAIN_PROC' || '_' || attribute1, 
            job_type   => 'PLSQL_BLOCK', 
            job_action => 'BEGIN 
                              MAIN_PROC(''' || attribute1 || ''', ''' || attribute2 || ''');
                           END;', 
            start_date => systimestamp , 
            auto_drop  => true,
            enabled    => true
        );
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('-- END OF WRAPPER PROC---' || SYSTIMESTAMP);
    END;
    

PROCEDURE MAIN_PROC( 
        attribute1          IN      VARCHAR2,
        attribute2          IN      VARCHAR2
    )
    AS
        sql_stmt    VARCHAR2(200);
    BEGIN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('-- START OF MAIN PROC---' || SYSTIMESTAMP);
        DBMS_SESSION.sleep(10);
        sql_stmt := 'INSERT INTO ASYNC_SAMPLE_TAB VALUES (:1, :2)';
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sql_stmt USING attribute1, attribute2;
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('-- END OF MAIN PROC---' || SYSTIMESTAMP);
    END;
END XX_ASYNC_DEMO_PKG;
```

Below is the command with which I'm trying to test above solution

```
exec XX_ASYNC_DEMO_PKG.WRAPPER_MAIN_PROC('Test101_1', 'Test101_2');
```

Comment: not an answer but `MAIN_PROC` doesn't need to be in the package header unless you want it accessible from outside the package, which from this, doesn't look like you want

Comment: Have you looked to see whether the job is running?  There could be other issues but the first one is that the job isn’t running with the context of the package.  You’d need to specify ‘package.procedure’

Comment: `DBMS_OUTPUT` called inside a background job prints its output to the nowhere, so you will not see any output after you submit the job. You may use some logging table or external file to print the result and obtaint it after the job completes

Comment: Don't build statements via string concatenation; use bind variables.

Comment: @astentx You should put that as an answer (because it is the answer, even if it's not the one the OP wants)

Comment: @MT0 Thank you, posted as an answer with more details.

Comment: @astentx could you please tell me how can I pass arguments in bind variable instead of string concatenation in above code, as I'm new to PLSQL so not aware of this. Thanks

Comment: Where are you expecting to see the output? Output from dbms_output.put_line within a scheduler job is captured in `user_scheduler_job_run_details.output`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As described [in the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/arpls/DBMS_OUTPUT.html#GUID-C1400094-18D5-4F36-A2C9-D28B0E12FD8C), the main purpose of `DBMS_OUTPUT` is debug messages to trace execution flow. It's also said there that it doesn't immediately return anything to the caller, but text is placed into the buffer and may be retrieved from there by the caller or the program itself (though, you cannot "get into" any other program flow and get anything from the executing code until the called unit is complete).

Scheduler doesn't retrieve the content of the buffer after it completes the job, so `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT*` called inside a background job has no effect and you cannot see any result.

You may use some logging table (with separate logging procedure executed in autonomous transaction not to have an influence or be influenced by the main transaction) or external file and `UTL_FILE` to send results here. Or use a general table that should be processed by the job and check results after it finishes.

**UPD**:
Below is a complete setup to demonstrate how to pass parameters to a callable and see its results.

- We'll log results into this table:

```
create table log_table (
    ts timestamp,
    val number,
    job_name varchar2(30)
)
```

- Then this procedure will be used to perform an action:

```
create or replace procedure proc_insert(
    p_val in number,
    p_job_name in varchar2
) as
begin
    insert into log_table(ts, val, job_name)
    values (systimestamp, p_val, p_job_name);
    commit;
end;
```

- This procedure will call our action procedure in a background job. We need to specify a number of parameters to override default values in a callable when creating a job. And then use [`DBMS_SCHEDULER.SET_JOB_[ARGUMENT|ANYDATA]_VALUE`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/arpls/DBMS_SCHEDULER.html#GUID-8B7CB779-6DE3-414C-999B-B0C82E71A19B) depending on the parameter type.

> ```
> create or replace procedure proc_insert_async(
>   p_call_id varchar2,
>   p_val number,
>   r_job_name out varchar2
> ) as
>   l_job_prefix constant varchar2(20) := 'LOG_TABLE_';
>   l_job_name varchar2(100) := l_job_prefix || p_call_id;
> begin
>   dbms_scheduler.create_job(
>     job_name => l_job_name,
>     job_type => 'STORED_PROCEDURE',
>     /*Callable unit - out API procedure*/
>     job_action => 'TEST_EAS.PROC_INSERT',
>     /*Number of args to be passed to the proc*/
>     number_of_arguments => 2,
>     /*Run immediately*/
>     start_date => sysdate,
>     enabled => false,
>     auto_drop => true
>   );
>
>   /*Pass parameters to the callable*/
>   dbms_scheduler.set_job_anydata_value (
>     job_name => l_job_name,
>     argument_position => 1,
>     argument_value => sys.anydata.convertNumber(p_val)
>   );
>   dbms_scheduler.set_job_argument_value(
>     job_name => l_job_name,
>     argument_position => 2,
>     argument_value => l_job_name
>   );
>
>   /*Start job*/
>   dbms_scheduler.enable(
>     name => l_job_name
>   );
>   
>   r_job_name := l_job_name;
> end;
> ```

- Finally, test this in action (sleep is added due to async nature of inserts to wait for results).

> ```
> declare
>     l_job_name varchar2(100);
> begin
>     proc_insert_async(
>         p_call_id => 'test1',
>         p_val => 1,
>         r_job_name => l_job_name
>     );
>
>     dbms_output.put_line(l_job_name);
>
>     proc_insert_async(
>         p_call_id => 'test2',
>         p_val => 10,
>         r_job_name => l_job_name
>     );
>
>     dbms_output.put_line(l_job_name);
>     dbms_session.sleep(3);
> end;
> /
> LOG_TABLE_test1
> LOG_TABLE_test2
>
>
> PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
> ```

```
select *
from log_table
```

| TS | VAL | JOB_NAME |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 25.11.22 10:52:37,310403000 | 10 | LOG_TABLE_test2 |
| 25.11.22 10:52:37,302992000 | 1 | LOG_TABLE_test1 |

Comment: I have updated the code where I'm trying to insert data into a table, but still its not working. nothing is getting inserted into table.

Comment: Did you commit the SQL transaction? Also, why use dynamic SQL (execute immediate) here at all? Why not just use `INSERT INTO ASYNC_SAMPLE_TAB VALUES (:attribute1, :attribute2);`

Comment: @pmdba Thanks, but how can i replace this with bind variables please suggest.  job_action => 'BEGIN 
         XX_ASYNC_DEMO_PKG.MAIN_PROC(''' || attribute1 || ''',''' || attribute2 || ''');
         END;',

Comment: @mushaikh Please check an updated answer